# Multi-level drop-down context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, infinite, multi-level

I am making a context(right click) menu plugin for jQuery, and it works fine for the first level. But I need it to have infinite levels. I already have the recursion down, but I think it's a problem with the showing/hiding. This is my code, so far: http://jsfiddle.net/H7GqA/4/ (Sorry for the messy code, plugin's for myself). The second-level item never appears, and I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance - Tanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `display:none` on the `.submenu` elements and you do nothing to show them.

If you want them to be always on add the following rule

```
#ContextMenu .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

if you want to do it on hover of their parent do

for modern browsers

```
#ContextMenu .item:hover > .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

---

I see the you have this code

```
    cm.find(".item:has(.submenu)").hover(function(){
        //$(this).find("ul").css('display', 'block');
        //alert('blabla_1');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
```

the should work (*if you uncomment the first line*) **and** move that code in the `doMain` function. Because where you currently have it the `#ContextMenu` element does not exist yet.. so the binding does not happen..

Comment: Thanks! Still have to work out some positioning, but it shows the submenu on hover!